# Reading txt file line by line in DataGrid View

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm completely new to VB.net and have been given a homework assignment. I need to be able to read certain lines and display them in a DataGridView. I have been able to link my .txt file to the DGV however it reads the whole file as opposed to the specific line. I have 4 buttons: btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4. I want each button to show the respective lines in the text file. After researching on-line for the past week I'm still stuck. If anyone could help me I would really appreciate it.

Text File ("database.txt")

> (Line1) c1 c2 c3
>
> (Line2) one 1-1 1-2
>
> (Line3) two 2-2 2-3
>
> (Line4) three 3-2 3-3
>
> (Line5) four 4-2 4-3

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click

        Dim lines = (From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines("database.txt") _
                    Select line.Split(CChar(vbTab))).ToArray
        For x As Integer = 0 To lines(0).GetUpperBound(0)
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(lines(0)(x), lines(0)(x))
        Next
        For x As Integer = 1 To lines.GetUpperBound(0)
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(lines(x))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The clue is in the "ReadAllLines" method, which will place all lines of the text file into one string. You are then splitting on Tab (not CrLf, which is end of line), so that is probably messing you up.

Comment: @Jeremy, no, it is the `ReadAllText` method that puts the whole file into a single `String`.  `ReadAllLines` splits the file on line breaks and then puts the individual lines into a `String` array.  That line of code is going to return a jagged array where each element of the outer array is a line and each inner array is the Tab-separated fields of that line.

Answer (score 0):

You did not describe the result you get, so I cannot tell what's wrong right now, as I am not on a computer and usually use c++/cli (visual c++). If I have to make a guess, I would say that you fill each file row into one DGV row, but you want just 1 row, not all. Correct?

Anyway, here are some suggestions:

- Do you have to read the file on each button click? If not, I would read it once, store the content and fill into the DGV when desired.
- Debug your code! Set a breakpoint at the start of the function, step over the code lines, check the variable content.
- Split up the code line `dim lines` into 3 or more separate lines to make it more readable.  Also helps at debugging.

Comment: Splitting `Dim lines` into seperate lines with `_` isn't going to help because it's a LINQ query. The debugger won't step into it.

Comment: I see. Shouldn't write answers at bed time... but she should use regular code as a beginner,  not messing up with LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

I made following assumptions based on what you had in your question:

- First line of the file was the column names
- The `(Line#)` was just there for reference and isn't in the actual file
- The number in the button name (`btn#`) was the row index that should be displayed in the DGV

I added a new button to the form that loads the data from the text file, parses it to a datatable and sets the `DataGridView1.DataSource` to that DataTable. The second method then creates a new datatable and imports the specified row from the main datatable and shows it in the DGV. Of course many will say you should use a `DataView` with a `DataView.RowFilter` for this rather than creating a new datatable, however this way works just the same.

```vb
Private txtDataTable As DataTable
Private Sub loadFileBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loadFileBtn.Click
    txtDataTable = New DataTable("txtContents")

    Dim txtContents As String()
    Try
        txtContents = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\StackOverflow\database.txt")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try

    Dim txtLines As New List(Of String())
    txtContents.ToList().ForEach(Sub(x) txtLines.Add(x.Split(CChar(vbTab))))

    If txtLines.Count > 0 Then
        txtLines.Item(0).ToList.ForEach(Sub(x) txtDataTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(x.ToString)))
        txtLines.RemoveAt(0)
    End If

    If txtLines.Count > 0 Then
        txtLines.ToList.ForEach(Sub(x) txtDataTable.Rows.Add(x.ToArray))
    End If
    DataGridView1.DataSource = txtDataTable
End Sub


Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click, btn2.Click, btn3.Click, btn4.Click
    If txtDataTable Is Nothing Then Return

    Dim rowIndex As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(DirectCast(sender, Button).Name.Replace("btn", String.Empty), rowIndex) Then
        rowIndex -= 1
    Else
        Return
    End If

    Dim TempTable As DataTable = txtDataTable.Clone
    If rowIndex < txtDataTable.Rows.Count Then
        TempTable.ImportRow(txtDataTable.Rows(rowIndex))
    End If

    DataGridView1.DataSource = TempTable
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Brandon, thank you for your response. You're solution works perfectly and has helped me a lot. However once the button is pressed I need the data to remain in the cell and the next button to display the second line of the .txt file in the row after it and so fort. (I only need this as I plan on doing a calculation in the last column once the user has pressed all the necessary items) Thank you.